# Jquery subtotal function conflicting with js gst function

Tags: javascript, jquery

O.k today is starting to be 1 step forward and 2 steps back. I have a Jquery function that does the price x qty = subtotal in the form and then each subtotal is calculated into a total, Which is all fine and dandy. I then have a plain js function that took that total value and added the gst and then a further subtotal figure which was created on it's own and works then at this point when i tried to move it over the gst and finial total functions won't work and i can't get any error codes out of it either. At this point i can only assume that the js script can't talk to the Jquery script or something is really wrong.

```
// Jquery script
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {  
    $(".qty, .tradeprice").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".qty").each(function() {
            var $qty = $(this),
                $row = $qty.closest('tr'),
                $tradePrice = $row.find('.tradeprice'),
                $subtotal = $row.find('.subtotal');
            subtotal = parseInt($qty.val(), 10) * parseFloat($tradePrice.val());
            total += subtotal;
            $subtotal.val(subtotal);
        });
        $('.total').val(total);
    }).change();
    });
</script>


// JS script
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePrice() {
          // Get the ex-GST price from its form element
    var exPrice = document.getElementById("ex-gst").value;
    var gstPrice = document.getElementById("gst").value;

    // Get the GST price
    gstPrice = exPrice * 0.1;
    var TPrice = parseInt(gstPrice) + parseInt(exPrice);

    // Set the GST price in its form element
    document.getElementById("gst").value = gstPrice;
    document.getElementById("inc-gst").value = TPrice;

    }
</script>

// bottom of HTML
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><input type='text' name='po101' id='po101'/></th>
            <td><input name='po102' type='text' id="po102"/></td>
            <td><input name='po103' type='text' id="po103" /></td>
            <td>$<input name='po104' type="text" class='tradeprice' id="po104" value="0" /></td>
            <th><input name='po105' type="text" class='qty' id="po105" value="0" /></th>
            <td><input name='po106' type='text' class='subtotal' id="po106" readonly="true" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th height='24' colspan="7">Total:<input type='text' id='Total' name='Total' class='total' readonly="true" onChange="updatePrice()"/></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th height='24' colspan="7"><div id='submit'><input type='submit' /></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th height='24' colspan="7">
            <input type='text' id="gst" name='gst' onChange="updatePrice()" />
            <input type='text' id="inc-gst" name='inc-gst' onChange="updatePrice(this.form)"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Two questions, why are you using both js and jquery? Why not only use jquery?

Comment: I was not sure how to write the function in Jquery, i am still new to it. Just been snippet hunting so far.

Comment: if you giv us the rest of the html it's easer to find the solution. We need the element with id ex-gst

Comment: ex-gst is the Total input

Comment: Ok, but in you code you are looking for a element with the id ex-gst (var exPrice = document.getElementById("ex-gst").value;) but you don't have any element with that id in you HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have now edited you code, and changed this line

```
var exPrice = document.getElementById("ex-gst").value;
```

to

```
var exPrice = document.getElementById("Total").value;
```

I have also updated the code by removing onChange() from HTML and added the trigger for your updatePrice() function to the change event.

And then this is the result (I have also added the jQuery version as comments, both will work).

```js
jQuery(function($) {
      $(".qty, .tradeprice").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".qty").each(function() {
          var $qty = $(this),
            $row = $qty.closest('tr'),
            $tradePrice = $row.find('.tradeprice'),
            $subtotal = $row.find('.subtotal');
          subtotal = parseInt($qty.val(), 10) * parseFloat($tradePrice.val());
          total += subtotal;
          $subtotal.val(subtotal);
        });
        $('.total').val(total);
        updatePrice();
      }).change();
    });

    function updatePrice() {
      // Get the ex-GST price from its form element
      var exPrice = document.getElementById("Total").value;
      //var exPrice = $('#Total').val() //this is jQuery
      var gstPrice = document.getElementById("gst").value;
      //var exPrice = $('#gst').val() //this is jQuery

      // Get the GST price
      gstPrice = exPrice * 0.1;
      var TPrice = parseInt(gstPrice) + parseInt(exPrice);

      // Set the GST price in its form element
      document.getElementById("gst").value = gstPrice;
      //$('#gst').val(gstPrice) //this is jQuery
      document.getElementById("inc-gst").value = TPrice;
      //$('#inc-gst').val(TPrice) //this is jQuery

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type='text' name='po101' id='po101' />
      </th>
      <td>
        <input name='po102' type='text' id="po102" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name='po103' type='text' id="po103" />
      </td>
      <td>$
        <input name='po104' type="text" class='tradeprice' id="po104" value="0" />
      </td>
      <th>
        <input name='po105' type="text" class='qty' id="po105" value="0" />
      </th>
      <td>
        <input name='po106' type='text' class='subtotal' id="po106" readonly="true" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height='24' colspan="7">Total:
        <input type='text' id='Total' name='Total' class='total' readonly="true" />
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height='24' colspan="7">
        <div id='submit'>
          <input type='submit' />
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height='24' colspan="7">
        <input type='text' id="gst" name='gst' />
        <input type='text' id="inc-gst" name='inc-gst' />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: still can't get the vales into the input forms, everything looks good tho and the stand alone version works. idk what could be conflicting

Comment: This is the line that crashes: <input type='text' id="inc-gst" name='inc-gst' onChange="updatePrice(this.form)" />

I don't understand what you want to do? The problem in the line is this.form that is undefined. You call the function udatePrice when the input inc-gst changes, but why you already do this one line above.

Comment: i just want to display the 10% gst figure and the subtotal and gst combined in input forms so i can process that into the next stage.